# Restricting arguments type for an overridden method

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

In my application I have a bunch of object of different types: say A, B, C, D.
Some of those objects can have a "*link*" with the others object meaning that, as example, the object A can own a set of the objects of type B.

I personally handled this problem creating an interface:

```
public interface Linkable<T extends Item>{

   public link(List<T extends Item>);

}
```

So that the object which can have a link with the others have to implement this interface:
let's say A, B and C implements `Linkable`

Moreover, I want to restrict the type of the objects that can be linked to some objects. As example, I want that objects of type A can be only linked to objects of type B and viceversa (the link always works in both ways).

My idea was to create then a hierarchy of interfaces in order to allow only specific type of links:
Let's say:

```
    ITEM
      |
------------
|          |
I1         I2     

A implements I1, I2
B implements I1
C implements I2
```

My example purpose is that instances of B can only be linked with instances of A, while instances of C cannot be linked with instances of B.

I personally perceive some holes in this design. In fact, I think that there is a need for more constraints I am not considering. When I will override the `Linkable::link` method in the classes A, B, C , it will have to accept subtypes of Item so, in the case of C, I will be able to add a link to instances of B, simply because `I1` and `I2` are both subtype of `ITEM`.

Moreover, I feel that also the `Item` type should be constrained to those who implement the `Linkable` interface.

How can I restrict the types during override? Am I missing something?

Comment: How is anyone supposed to call `Linkable::link` if they don't know what kinds of elements in it will accept?  Maybe that interface is useless and you should just get rid of it.  `A`, `B`, and `C` can still have their own `link` methods.

Comment: I wanted to use it to mark which objects "support" a link operation and to oblige those classes to define the link method. Linkable::link will only accept object implementing Items. My problem is exactly that I don't know how to restrict it more for the specific class.

Comment: How would the clients of this interface actually use it?

Comment: They will call A::link(List<B> listOfBs). I would that they won't be able to do B::link(List<C> listOfCs).

Comment: can't you use instanceof operator to check whether an object should be linked or not

Comment: instanceOf is a possible way. I was wondering about a more architectural solution.

Comment: Do A, B, and C have an inheritance relationship with each other, aside from linking?  You seem to be implying it, but I see no explicit statement in that regard.

Comment: no inheritance relationships among each others